# Terminal commands to add NEW custom browser to Preferred Applications?

Tags: command-line, browser

I would like to know the terminal commands to add *new* custom browser to Preferred Applications?

I don't mean selecting a browser using:

```
sudo update-alternatives –config x-www-browser
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me with the following:

What are the Terminal Commands to add a NEW custom browser to Preferred Applications?

I would like links in other files to work as well, for example, when I click on a link in a `.pdf`, I am currently getting the following error:

```
Failed to execute child process "/opt/iron-linux-32/iron" (No such file or directory)
```

I also tried:

```
$ /usr/share/iron/iron
Failed to execute child process "/usr/share/iron/iron" (Permission denied)
```

It also failed when I elevated permission.

I have tried:

```
sudo gnome-default-applications-properties
```

Then, in the "Command" box entered:

```
/opt/iron-linux-32/iron %s
```

(with and without the `%s`)

I have also tried:

```
/usr/share/iron/iron %s
```

I am using Ubuntu 10.04. I want to use SRWare Iron.
Note: There might be an issue as well with privileges.

I am using this as an opportunity to learn how to use the command line, and am really stuck. Seems like it should be possible, but I might be getting stuck on syntax.

Comment: Tried https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open ?

Comment: first, thanks for response (and apologies for slow reply, took me a while to get to this)...

Comment: Thanks for response...Finally got it to work using a program called "System Settings":

System Settings
Version 1.0
Using KDE Development Platform 4.4.5 (KDE 4.4.5)
(c) 2009, Ben Cooksley

1. First, I elevated my permissions to root (admin)
2. Using "System Settings"
3. General Tab
4. Under the "Personal" Section, select "Default Applications"
5. Go to "Web Browser," (go to 2nd selection) "In the following browser," search around and select "iron."

I could not get Xdg-open to work. Not saying that it doesn't work, just saying "I" couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Answer from the original poster:

Finally got it to work using a program called "System Settings": System Settings Version 1.0 Using KDE Development Platform 4.4.5 (KDE 4.4.5) (c) 2009, Ben Cooksley

1. First, I elevated my permissions to `root` (admin)
2. Using "System Settings"
3. General Tab
4. Under the "Personal" Section, select "Default Applications"
5. Go to "Web Browser," (go to 2nd selection) "In the following browser," search around and select "iron."

I could not get `Xdg-open` to work. Not saying that it doesn't work, just saying "I" couldn't get this to work

Answer (score 0):

When you can apply `update-alternatives` that you installed your target application with apt-get or dpkg.(in deb system)
But when you have binary file you should do it:
1. in directory `/usr/share/applications/` exist many file that explain for you preferred application, copy a file from them and change it.
2. then add it to `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`
Of course i did it  7  8 months old. i didn't recall but i think , you do a bit more than my recommendation.